# Cabal build all failed with "Failed to build Diff-0.5"

Tags: cabal

```
Preprocessing library for base58-bytestring-0.1.0..
Building library for base58-bytestring-0.1.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Data.ByteString.Base58.Internal ( src/Data/ByteString/Base58/Internal.hs, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Base58/Internal.o, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Base58/Internal.dyn_o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Data.ByteString.Base58 ( src/Data/ByteString/Base58.hs, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Base58.o, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Base58.dyn_o )

src/Data/ByteString/Base58.hs:15:1: error: [-Wunused-imports, -Werror=unused-imports]
    The import of ‘Control.Applicative’ is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from ‘Control.Applicative’
    To import instances alone, use: import Control.Applicative()
   |
15 | import Control.Applicative
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: What are you building? What versions of `ghc` and `cabal` are you using?

Comment: I am using ghc 8.10.7 and cabal 3.6.2.0

Comment: Ok,but what are you building?

Comment: I am running cabal build all in the cardano-node directory as per the directions in this readme: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node-wiki/blob/main/docs/getting-started/install.md

Comment: Ok, so you are building `cardano-node`. The warning you posted is from a library that cabal has pulled from Hackage. Its a *warning*, not an error. so is should just continue to compile. That warning can be ignored.

Comment: Actually I started from the instructions from here (https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#linux), which told me to use cabal 3.6.2. However, the link I posted from the previous comment uses cabal 3.8.1, so I am using that instead.

Comment: Anything after cabal `3.6.2` is fine.